# How to read only data from a file (ignore strings)?

Tags: java

In java, how can you read only data from a file, and ignore the strings preceding it? Please guys, I did a lot of research but I couldn't seem to find it.

Here is a sample textfile:

```
number of courses:3
course numbers:219 214 114
arrival Probabilities:0.4 0.6 0.8
min time:2
max time: 4
num cups:1
simulation time:50
number of tas:2
```

Now as you guys can see, I just want to read the numbers.

My current code is the following, but I run into an InputMismatchException due to obvious reasons (It reads string first instead of integer):

```
//Read file
        while(input.hasNext()){
            //Read Number of Courses

            numCourses = input.nextInt();
            courseNumbers = new int[numCourses]; //Initialize the size of courseNumbers array.
            arrivalProbability = new double[numCourses]; //Initialize the size arrivalProbability array.

            //Read the CourseNumbers, numCourses times.
            for(int i = 0; i < numCourses; i++){
                courseNumbers[i] = input.nextInt();

            }

            //Read the arrivalProbability, numCourses times.
            for(int i = 0; i < numCourses; i++){
                arrivalProbability[i] = input.nextDouble();

            }

            //Read minTime
            minTime = input.nextInt();

            //Read maxTime
            maxTime = input.nextInt();

            //Read number of Coffee cups
            numCups = input.nextInt();

            //Read simulation time
            officeHrTime = input.nextInt();

            //Read the number of TAs
            numTAs = input.nextInt();
        }
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have `:` (colon) before each number?

Comment: you must read the strings and discard them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

- read a line
- parse the line, determine which part is the label and which part is the data
- use the label to determine how to store the data

Don't use `nextInt`, use `nextLine`. You would need to do a lot more error checking than I have included here, but I would do it something like this:

```
int numCourses;
int[] courseNumbers; // I would use a list here, but sticking with your data types for clarity.

while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] lineParts = line.split(":");
    String label = lineParts[0];
    String value = lineParts[1];

    if(label.equals("number of courses")) {
        numCourses = Integer.parseInt(value);
    } else if(label.equals("course numbers")) {
        String[] courseNumberStr = value.split(" ");
        courseNumbers = new int[numCourses]; // you probably want to make sure numCourses was set and courseNumStr has the correct number of elements
        for(int i = 0; i < courseNumberStr.length; i++) {
            courseNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(courseNumberStr[i]);
        }
    } else if( /* handle the rest of the inputs */) {
        // etc
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!